# Selenium unable to find element of icon

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

[image: Source I am trying to scrap from]

My code so far, result returned to be not be found.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:/geckodriver")
dominos_pg = "https://www.dominos.ca/pages/order/#!/locations/search/"
driver.get(dominos_pg)
time.sleep(5)
elem_class = driver.find_element_by_class_name("Carryout c-carryout circ-icons__icon circ-icons__icon--carryout")
```

Any advice/suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Please just paste the HTML in as a formatted block rather than including a screenshot.

Comment: Also it looks like your code isn't quite complete - where's your `find` call?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:/geckodriver")
dominos_pg = "https://www.dominos.ca/pages/order/#!/locations/search/"
driver.get(dominos_pg)
time.sleep(5)
elem_class = driver.find_element_by_class_name("Carryout c-carryout circ-icons__icon circ-icons__icon--carryout")


print(elem_class)
```

If That Don't Work It's Mean Your Url Is Not Correct Because I See There is no element `Carryout`

Comment: This does not work, returned unable to find the class you stated. I copied and pasted the URL, so not sure which part went wrong.

Comment: When I Open That Url I Can't See Any Class There

Comment: The Inspect Image Class Is Not That Url

Comment: When We Open Your Url We See There is Url Change You Can Also Check By Try!

Comment: And The Error You Are Telling It's Also Saying Can't Find That Class Because your Url is not right

Comment: @Sen send me any contacting link so i can give prefect script that can help you and also for more details

Comment: @Sen Send Me Your Contact Link So We Can Discus Better!

Comment: Sorry, but the URL you used is not correct either, so not sure what is the workaround here.

Comment: @Sen I'm Sorry I Tried My Best To Solve Your issue But i Can't I'm Very Sorry I Can't Fix Your Issue!

Comment: I was able to figure it out, I used find_element_by_xpath. URL was not the issue. Thank you for your suggestion and effort.

Answer (score 0):

Your url is incorrect . Please find below working solution:

**Solution 1:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as Wait




driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\New folder\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.dominosaruba.com/en/pages/order/#!/locations/search/?type=Carryout")



driver.switch_to.frame(2);
CarryoutElement=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Carryout')]")))

CarryoutElement.click()
```

**Solution 2:**

```
CarryoutElement=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='Carryout c-carryout circ-icons__icon circ-icons__icon--carryout']")))

CarryoutElement.click()
```

**solution 3:**

```
CarryoutElement=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@data-quid='easy-order-locator-carryout']")))

CarryoutElement.click()
```

Comment: This does not help me, I cannot actively choose a location in my area.

Comment: Check your question, you have mentioned you are unable to find element and now you have changed your requirement. Also you have not provided proper information on question. URL is also wrong initially. I would request you to please accept this answer if you happy with your first question and then raise another question with new requirement with proper information.

Comment: Sorry, are you suggesting using alternative URL as a solution? That is not exactly what I am looking for so I will not be accepting it. I am not sure what do you mean by wrong URL, I do not think the URL is location bound.

Comment: Your information is uncleared and also question is wrong

Comment: If my information/question was unclear, I would think you'd asked what I was looking for instead of answering. Regardless, suggesting an alternative URL when I have already explicitly state which URL I am using does not "answer my question". I do appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 0):

After much browsing, the I used xpath through the label